# Azure Logic App integration with Service Bus Queue initiating duplicate run when concurrent control is set to 1 (run sequentially)

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus

**Scenario I want to achieve:**

1. I am sending around 100 messages to the service bus queue
2. I have a logic app which has "Service Bus Message received" as the first step with the following settings:

[image]

3. Also I have the Concurrency Control limit turned on and set as 1 so that only one instance of logic app run at given time:

[image]

4. The Logic App process takes around 15 to 20 minutes to complete.
5. From the service bus side I have the following settings for the queue:

[image]

**Issue I am facing**

1. I can see the Logic App is running only one instance at a time.
2. But somehow the duplicate message is coming and again same message triggering the logic app instance (Though I am using the following service bus trigger which says that it will autocomplete the message)

[image]

Comment: Auto-complete means it reads one or more messages

Comment: Did you check to see if the sender is not sending duplicated messages? did you also try enabling duplication detection :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/enable-duplicate-detection

Comment: @BrunoLucasAzure: Yes sender is not sending any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same and worked fine for me.
Can suggest three approaches:

1. Try enabling duplicate detection:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/enable-duplicate-detection
   [image]
2. Try using "peek lock" to see if the lock improves anything. remember to add a task to complete at the end of the flow
3. Start over to see if anything got corrupted.

I've used "peek lock" trigger with large batches and parallelism enabled and didn't have any duplicates. even when going though thousands of records

Can you find any clues in the insights?

Comment: Are you from Azure team ? I can ping you in teams to elaborate the problem.